# $\int_a^b{f(x)dx}=0$ if $f$ is zero a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show that if a function $f$ is zero almost everywhere then $\int_a^b{f(x)dx=0}$.

I have shown the inverse implication and have seen other solutions to that, but none with the implication in the forward direction.

For the inverse, I used MCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set where $f$ is non-zero has null measure. Hence the integral on that set equals $0$. It is well know that if you integrate on a set of null measure the integral is always $0$.
The integral where $f$ is $0$ is of course $0$.
So you can conclude that the total integral is $0$.

Comment: Brilliant. So if I just integrate over the two disjoint sets, one with f(x)=0 and one not, then just sum these two, which is the same as the integral of the union of these two disjoint sets?

Comment: Exactly! You use the integral additivity on those two disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

$\int f= \int_{f=0} f + \int_{f\neq 0} f =0+0$, where the first term is zero because the integrand is zero everywhere and the second is zero because the set over which you integrate has measure zero.